# Lazy Loading a Repeating Iframe Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a lazy-load code block here:

```
(function($){

    var items = [];

    function winPos(win) {
        return { x: 0, y: 0, x2: win.width() - 1, y2: win.height() - 1 };
    }

    function pos(win, el) {
        var p = el.offset();
        var x = p.left - win.scrollLeft();
        var y = p.top - win.scrollTop();
        return { x: x, y: y, x2: x + el.width() -1, y2: y + el.height() - 1 };
    }

    function intersects(a, b) {
        return !(a.x2 < b.x || a.x > b.x2 || a.y2 < b.y || a.y > b.y2);
    }

    function check(win, w, item) {
        var p = pos(win, $(item.el));
        var s = intersects(w, p);
        if (s != item.shown) {
            item.shown = s;
            (s ? item.show : item.hide).call(item.el);
        }
    }

    $.fn.visible = function(show, hide){
        var win = $(window), w = winPos(win);
        return this.each(function(i, el){
            var item = { el: el, show: show, hide: hide, shown: false };
            items.push(item);
            check(win, w, item);
        });
    };

    $(window).on('scroll resize', function(e){
        var win = $(window), w = winPos(win);
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            check(win, w, items[i]);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

// Lazy loading images plugin

(function($){

    $.fn.lazyImage = function(){
        return this.visible(function(){
            $(this).append($('<img>', {'src':  $(this).data('src') }).css('opacity', 0).load(function(){
                $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
            }));
        }, function(){
            $(this).empty();
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

// Usage

$('div').lazyImage();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/u7bcms27/

I want to lazy load each iframe div.

*

Here's my code, that gets links and titles from the Reddit API, and loads the videos into Iframes.

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/cleanupearth.json')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(res=>res.data.children)
.then(res=>res.map(post=>({
  // author: post.data.author,
  link: post.data.url,
  img: post.data.thumbnail,
  title: post.data.title
})))
.then(res=>res.map(render))
.then(res=>console.log(res))

const app = document.querySelector('#app');
const render = post => {
 const node = document.createElement('div');  
   node.innerHTML= `${post.title}`;
  node.className= 'clip-title';
    app.appendChild(node);
 //node.style.fontSize = "50px";

 var regExp = /^.*(youtu\.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var url = post.link;
// var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPmKEi4xXMg";
var match = url.match(regExp);
var strippedURL = match[2];
//alert("strippedURL is " + strippedURL); 
if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
    console.log(match[2]);
} else {
  //error
  console.log('error');
}

var a = document.createElement('iframe');
// iframe.id = 'appiframe';
  a.className = "clip-content"
a.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + strippedURL; //add your iframe path here
a.width = "100%";
a.height = "100%";
a.padding = "500px";
app.style.textAlign = "center";
document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(a);
}
```

*

Here's an fiddle of the two snippets together.

https://jsfiddle.net/p5tL6jvr/

The original snippet creates an empty array called items:

```
var items = [];
```

and loads images into an append function;

```
$(this).append($('<img>', {'src':  $(this).data('src') }).css('opacity', 0).load(function()
```

I could load the entire id=#app div into the items array, and swap the img line for a line that creates iframes. What is the best way to approach this?

BTW, if anyone knows of a succinct way to do this in pure Javascript, instead of JQuery, that would be interesting to read.

Comment: The jQuery is included in the javascript settings dialog (click on the settings wheel in the javascript pane).

Comment: Never noticed that, I was looking at the left hand panel. I'll delete that question. :)